# How can I turn the items within a list that is within another list, turn them from char to ints

Tags: python, string, list, integer

```
[['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['2', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '6'], ['4', '5'], ['5', '6']]
```

This is what I'm getting but I am trying to return:

```
[[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4]...etc
```

My code to take each line of the file:

```
##takes each line of the text file
filename = input("Enter filename:")
with open(filename) as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        words = line.split()
        lines.append(words)
```

Comment: Replace `words = line.split()` with `words = [ìnt(word) for word in line.split()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each of the "words" and cast them as an int using something like `int(word)`. Be aware, his could throw exceptions if the string isn't formatted as an int, so it would be wise to include a try/catch

Answer (score 0):

Itterrate through sublist and type to `int` .

```
nested = [['1', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '3'], ['1', '4'], ['2', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['2', '5'], ['3', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['3', '6'], ['4', '5'], ['5', '6']]

final = [[int(e) for e in item] for item in nested]
print(final)
```

Gives #

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 5], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score -2):

The remove() method removes the first matching element which is passed as an argument from the list the pop() method removes an element at a given index and will als0 the removed the item.

Comment: As written, there is no visible relation whatsoever with the question. Is this a GPT answer? Please, elaborate to make the relation to the question clearer.